# Install Django1.8 for Python 3.4

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8

I had Python 2.7 in my system by default, and I installed it and also installed Django 1.11 with it. Now I want to upgrade to a newer version of both and in order to do so, I accidentally deleted Django from usr/local/lib/python2.7. I'm not sure if the problem is because of this. Here are the errors that keep showing up:

1. When I tried to remove the old version of Django:

   ```
   $ python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: No module named 'django'
   ```
2. When I check the Django version installed

   ```
   $ python3 -m django --version
   /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named django
   ```
3. By doing `pip freeze`

   ```
   pip freeze
   Brlapi==0.6.1
   Django==1.8
   ```

I really want to learn Django, can you please help me with this installation?

Comment: You have two versions of Python on your system, try `pip3 install django`

Comment: It gets installed but not able to import django to python3
`$ python3 
Python 3.4.5 (default, Dec 13 2016, 02:55:02) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> import django 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named 'django' 
>>>`

Answer (score 0):

Installing with pip system wide is usually considered an anti pattern. You should really use virtualenv, you can a short introduction to virtualenv here:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Back to your problem you seem to not know that python and python3 are two separated implementation, thus what you installed with one is not seen by other. Try anyway reinstalling django with

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

For python3 the related pip should be called something like pip3.

Comment: I'm new at python :D . Btw, as you said, I ran this command and still not able to import django to python3 
$ python3
Python 3.4.5 (default, Dec 13 2016, 02:55:02) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
>>>

Comment: If you want it in python3 you should use pip3, but please create a python3 virtualenv (virtualenv -p python3.4) and work there.

Comment: Thanks for virtualenv information :)
I used pip3 and still got the error